# How can I determine whether a file in git is executable?

Tags: git

If I have a file in a git repository, how can I determine whether a given revision of the file is executable or not?

I know that git keeps track of whether files are executable or not, and `git show` will show changes in execute permissions.  For example, the output of `git show` on a given revision might include:

```
diff --git file file
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

which indicates that the file acquired execute permission.

I want to determine whether the current revision, or any specified revision, of a specified file has execute permission.

(Background: I have a wrapper script that extracts a specified version of a file using

```
git show $commit:./$filename > ./$filename.$commit
```

I want to run `chmod +x` on the new file if and only if that version of the file executable in the repository.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`git ls-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree), passing in the ref and file path you want to inspect.

For example, `git ls-tree HEAD foo.txt` will give something like

```
100644 blob 3e1d68d0714fd3d46ec22a685e317f0cf47f5e83    foo.txt
```

The 644 in the first column indicates a non-executable file. 755 would indicate an executable file.